# Stripe - Upgrade/downgrade plan response in webhook

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Following code I'm using to upgrade a user's plan:

```
$subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::all(array('customer'=>$customerId,'limit'=>10));

        $subscription_id = $subscription->data[0]->id;

        $subscription = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($subscription_id);
        $updatePlan = [
            'cancel_at_period_end' => false,
            'items' => [
                [
                    'id' => $subscription->items->data[0]->id,
                    'plan' => planPrefix.$packageId,
                ],
            ],
            'tax_percent' => $package_tax,
        ];

        \Stripe\Subscription::update($subscription_id, $updatePlan);

        //Create invoice now
        $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::create([
            'customer' => $customerId,
        ]);

        $invoiceId = $invoice->id;
        //Pay invoice now
        $invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::retrieve($invoiceId);
        $invoice->pay();
```

And when stripe get paid to that newly created invoice, The event "invoice.payment_succeeded" is triggered to my webhook where I update my database accordingly.

The problem is that stripe sends me previous plan id with the accurate invoice.
E.g., If User A subscribes to plan id 1 then stripe sends me object for the newly subscribed plan details to my webhook with accurate data, but when User A
upgrades to plan whose id is 2, stripe sends me data with the event of "invoice.payment_succeeded" where I can find all the data related to subscription update but the issue is with the plan id. The plan id stripe sends me is old one i.e., 1 instead of 2, and when User A upgrade to plan id 3 then it sends me plan id 2 in the webhook notification.

Any help in this matter would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you listen for the `customer.subscription.updated` event, this will return the info for the plan you just switched your user to. Also contained in the returned Json is the `"previous_attributes"` which contains the old plan details.

Comment: I'm listening to 'invoice.payment_succeeded' when user upgrades/downgrades his subscription.I noticed that when a user subscribes first time,It returns actual plan id in $event_json['data']['object']['lines']['data'][0]['plan']['id'] to which user subscribed and when user updates his subscription and the change I found in the event response are few new elements in which we can find updated plan id as well with the following field:
$event_json['data']['object']['lines']['data'][1]['plan']['id'] so I just used ifelse to get the plan id to which user subscribed.Though Its working fine for me now